# How to use Conditional Formatting to change text color to match conditional fill color

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have used the Conditional Formatting to change the Cell fill color based on the percentage number.  However, I would like to hide the text so I just have a bunch of colored squares with no value showing.  Is there Conditional Formatting that will change the text color to match the background cell fill color or something else I could do? I am in Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption that you used the "greater than" and/or "less than" rules to apply conditional formatting to the cells based on the percentage number. If you use the "custom format" option you can select that the "fill" and "font" be the same color. BTW this would also work for some of the other conditional formatting rules.

[image]

Comment: Nope, I am using the "Color Scales" Conditional Formatting

Comment: My thoughts would be going to individual cells and picking a **font color** that matches the **fill color**, or using one of the Conditional Formatting selections that allows for **Custom Format** such as I mentioned above. I don't know how you would do what you are asking using the "Color Scales" Conditional Formatting which is not to say that it can't be done. There are a lot of Excel experts on here, perhaps one of them will educate us both.

Comment: I think that I may have discovered a way to accomplish what you are trying to do. Select the cells that contain the text which you want to hide. Open the cell format dialog (Ctrl + 1). Select "Custom". In the "Type" box input ;;; (three semicolons). Select OK. This will hide the text in the selected cells.