# How to use conditional formatting based on a different column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, formatting, conditional-formatting, highlighting

Looking to format a column background color using conditional formatting based on the integer value from a [different](https://superuser.com/a/1275535/1903203) column.  Where or how is the second column referenced?

Bing AI, copilot, says:

> here is conditional formatting in excel? Copilot In Excel, you can
> find the Conditional Formatting feature in the Home tab. Here’s how to
> access it:
>
> Open your Excel workbook. Navigate to the Home tab (located at the top
> of the Excel window). Look for the Styles group within the Home tab.
> Click on the Conditional Formatting button. Once you click on it, a
> menu will appear with various options for applying conditional
> formatting to your data. You can use this feature to highlight cells
> based on specific rules, create color scales, and more. Happy
> formatting!
>
> For more detailed instructions and examples, you can also refer to the
> official Microsoft support page1.

How is the formatting for column B calculated from column K?  Specifically, where column k is greater than 30 I'd like to change the background color for the corresponding cell in column B.

screenshot:

[conditional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFkqD.png)

using MS Office Standard 2019.

Like this:

https://superuser.com/a/915576/1903203

but calculating based on a different column than that being formatted.

What I've tried is to use this formula:

[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLOyX.png)

Format values where this is true:

```
=$K:$K>5
```

but clearly that's not the correct formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do :

[image]

---

- Select the range `Column B` here.
- From `Home` Tab --> Goto `Conditional Formatting`
- Click `New` --> From `New Formatting Rule` Window --> Select the last rule
- Last Rule --> `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
- In the edit the rule description write this formula:

---

`=K9>30`

---

- Click `Format` and use preferred formatting as per your choice.
- Click `OK` twice.

---

Comment: that looks great!  I'll try it now.  Thanks.